Parallel processing with PyTorch on GPU
I have to run 1350 Reinforcement Learning experiments that take ~10 min of time when run sequentially.
As the experiments are independent (all on the same NN architecture but individual models and parameters) and the models used are very small, parallelization could drastically speed-up execution. When run sequentially, only a fraction of available GPU RAM is being used.
I chose to use google colaboratory with T4 GPU and the torch.multiprocessing package for parallelization on GPU. Code looks like this:
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool

def run_experiment(param):
   # create environment
   # create agent (model) with param
   # let agent interact with environment
   return

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
   params = ...
  
   mp.set_start_method('spawn') # CUDA runtime does not support fork method

   num_p = 8                    # num of parallel processes


   with Pool(num_p) as p:
      p.map(run_experiment, params)

I do gain a speed-up when using num_p = 8 but the total execution time would still be > 28 h and GPU RAM is still barely used (slightly more than before).
My question:
How can I exploit the available GPU RAM to parallelize the training?
In order to better understand what's happening, I conducted an experiment with smaller jobs:



Total jobs
Num processes
GPU RAM usage (GB)
Exe time first run (s)
Total exe time (s)




16
2
0.3
245
1997


16
4
0.6
269
1155


16
8
1.2
451
922


16
16
2.5
900
942


32
8
1.2
452
1893


32
16
2.5
895
1891



The results are not what I expected. Shouldn't total execution speed double whenever I double the number of processes as long as I don't exceed available RAM (15 GB available)? Also, shouldn't execution time for the first run (until the first run of run_experiment() is finished) be more or less the same for each row?
How to do GPU parallelization properly in my case?

Q1 : What analysis ( of resources used or possible to use + of add-on overheads, that your code has to pay in addition to the base amount of work ( given repeating the base-work of 1350 RL-parametrisation tasks took 1350 x 10 minutes ~ 225 hours retains the same amount of operations, now not executed on 4+ GHz but on some mere 1.5 GHz SM-SIMD fabric ecosystem ) to claim an expected speedup? Q2 : What tests have you executed ( with what results ) to claim the Python-side pool of resources cannot use GPU-resources otherwise but in an exclusive, SERIAL manner? Q3 : Tried other tools?

GPUs can run multiple cuda kernels asynchronously, but the GPU has a limited number of SMs. If one kernel saturates the SMs, the GPU can't parallel process. This could limit parallel performance. You could also be bottlenecked on CPU or disk i/o for loading/processing data.

@Karl Thanks! I think this points at the solution to my problem. How do I choose the optimal number of parallel processes to run with torch.multiprocessing with respect to the number of kernels and SMs and their saturation?

@user3666197 I added experimental results to the question.
